# how to get selected value from a paginated gridview into a dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a project in Asp.NET and I have implemented pagination in the GridView. If I navigate to the next page and select a row, it does not display its values into the dropdownlist, but it does display the values into the TEXTBOXES. Please help!

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        txtempcode.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text.ToString();
        txtfname.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text.ToString();
        ddljob.SelectedValue = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text.ToString().Trim();
        ddllocate.SelectedValue = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[4].Text.ToString().Trim();
        ddlgend.SelectedValue = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[5].Text.ToString().Trim();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: How and when are the dropdowns getting populated?  It's possible you're assigning a selected value before any values exist. I would set a breakpoint in the code and see what items exist in the dropdowns at the time of the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

```
    ddljob.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text.ToString().Trim();
    ddllocate.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[4].Text.ToString().Trim();
    ddlgend.Text = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[5].Text.ToString().Trim();
```

This will set the text of the dropdown menus to a text contained in respective cells in the gridview. If you have all possible variations of the values, which may be in the gridview, already loaded in respective dropdown menus, then you can use this:

```
    ddljob.Value = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text.ToString().Trim();
    ddllocate.Value = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[4].Text.ToString().Trim();
    ddlgend.Value = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[5].Text.ToString().Trim();
```

But this is contingent on the values matching exactly.

Oh! just though of the thing, how about this:
First:  Add it to as an ListItem
Second: Select it.

```
    ddljob.Items.Add(GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text.ToString().Trim());
    ddljob.SelectedValue = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text.ToString().Trim();
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: If the issue only occurs after pagination, I'm thinking it's a postback issue.

Comment: Yes it occurs after pagination, i tried to resolve by set postback to false, but still not working

Comment: I would then keep the source in the session, and operate on that instead of GridView. Also, make sure you construct everything before calling GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged